# Migration of SharePoint from 2007 to 2010/2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, migration, upgrade

I have a requirement to migrate the sharepoint portal from 2007 to 2010 and 2013.

Please help me with the possible ways in doing it.

Let me know the do's and don't also

Comment: This question has been answered multiple times before here, and a simple internet search will get you great Microsoft resources

Comment: @BennySkogberg Its all well and good saying that its a possible duplicate but the question is slightly different and obviously wasnts more info than whats posted.

Comment: @RobertLindgren isnt what this forum all about? ;) sometimes info is hidden and not everyone is good at googling as you or me :) , when people google it usualy shows this site up as the work is mostly done so why not ask the question directly!

Comment: Sure it is, but I do not agree with you that this question is any different, and the Microsoft resources you get as the top results from Google in this case are pretty good (as I guess you noticed when you wrote your answer ;))

Comment: tooshay , he asked a question and i answered! some people find the info daugnting and confusing and want some direction, thats what i gave ;) as i said you know how to google as you know what to put in the search bar ;)

Answer (score 0):

this is for 2007 to 2010

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303420(v=office.14).aspx

this is for 2007 to 2013

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303420(v=office.15).aspx

you need to be more clear on what you want upgrading?

how is your system built and how the next one is built? this will play a huge factor to upgrading the system! as some techiques require some key features!

ask yourself!

> There are 3 or 4 major questions and a few variables to those
>   questions that frame this conversion:
>
> •What is the current state of your SharePoint 2007 environment?  ◦Do
>   you have any customizations that have been implemented that are
>   business critical or need to be taken into major consideration? ◦What
>   is the current state of your SharePoint infrastructure?
>
> ■Do you have SQL Server 2008 implemented?
>
> ■Is your organization ready for virtualization of 64-bit server farms?
>
> •How much content and what types of content do you have in your
>   SharePoint 2007 environment?  ◦Do you have major “team site sprawl” or
>   multiple sites with the same content? ◦Have you identified the owners
>   of this content and\or Site Owners?
>
> ■More than likely some original site owners may no longer work in that
>   department or others have taken on that responsibility ◦Has your
>   organization broken “the SharePoint Golden Rule” by storing content in
>   multiple locations (i.e. Rather than the SharePoint “one version of
>   the truth” concept)
>
> ■80% of organizations have broken this rule so you are not alone, it’s
>   time to get a handle of content sprawl and “surface” a piece of
>   content in multiple locations instead of storing it in multiple
>   locations
>
> •Do you have Microsoft Office 2010 installed within your organization?
>   ◦Is there going to be any issues training users and do you have
>   internal training strategies in place and\or what has worked in the
>   past for training your organization’s team members? ◦Are users already
>   comfortable with the “ribbon”
>
> •What is your licensing situation? Can you opt to go right to
>   SharePoint 2013 with your licensing agreement or is SharePoint 2010
>   you’re only licensing option?

http://www.aiim.org/community/blogs/expert/Should-Your-SharePoint-2007-Platform-Migrate-to-2010-or-Go-Right-to-SharePoint-2013

there are several migration paths you can take but as i said some need extra requirements like database upgrade:

1. In-Place Upgrade
2. Gradual Upgrade
3. Database migration (advanced)
4. Site and List Definition upgrade

as im presuming here, i would think you want to migrate your 2007 sharepoint enviroment to 2010 or 2013.

the above would be used for 2007 to 2010! reason being 2007 to 2013 would be option 3 as your skipping a generation and some things are fased out like In-Place Upgrade.

You can upgrade which is recommended by microsoft to do Database migration (advanced)
that would require you to migrate your content database from 2007 to 2010 and from 2010 to 2013!

> SharePoint 2013 does not support in-place upgrade for an existing
>   environment. You must use the database-attach upgrade method to
>   upgrade your databases to a new environment that is based on
>   SharePoint 2013. Also, to provide more flexibility to farm
>   administrators and site administrators, the upgrade process has
>   changed to separate upgrade of the software and databases from upgrade
>   of the sites.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617150.aspx

2007 to 2013 step by step upgrade

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee947141(v=office.15)

2007 to 2010 step by step upgrade

http://sharepoint2010blog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/how-to-upgrade-to-sharepoint-2010-using.html

topologies for upgrade 2010

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262747(v=office.14).aspx

topologies for upgrade 2013

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262747(v=office.15).aspx

as iv stated its hard to tell you what method to use as i dont know how your current system is setup and what you really want! If your system is going to be on a seperate machine than you can use the advanced method! if not you just merley upgrade the current system!

I would personaly recommend going from 2007 to 2013! via 2010. 2007 to 2010 is not a big jump and would tie up any issue that may arrise for when you upgrade from 2010 to 2013, as an example you have some features that exist in 2007 and 2010 but not in 2013, some that exist in 2013 but not in 2007. In 2010 you need to set the site to claims based authentication befor upgrading as a requirement for upgrade http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx ! 2013 is a better platform to use as it offers more tools and a better look/customisation compared to 2010 but you need to factor in the cost and time!

sorry for the links but i cant past in all the info as this post would be stupidly massive and would be horrible to read!

so just to make it clear that the link for 2007 to 2013 step by step upgrade is the way to go and is recommended for 2013! Its the same way i use for 2003 to 2010!