# Pre installing solution doesn't solve the issue with the pre attach test

Tags: 2010, migration, content-database, solution

I want to attach a database to a newly created web application.

I have a database which is correct. I execute the PowerShell script:

```
Test-SPContentDatabase -Name ContentDB -WebApplication http://webapp
```

And it says, ok there are some items which are referenced in the Content Database but not installed.

Like this:

> Category        : MissingSiteDefinition Error           : True
>   UpgradeBlocking : False Message         : 188 Sites in database
>   [ContentDB] has reference(s) to a missing site definition, Id =
>   [75820], Lcid = [1
>                     033]. Remedy          : The site definitions with Id 75820 is referenced in the database [ContentDB], but is not installed
>   on th
>                     e current farm. The missing site definition may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the
>   site definiti
>                     on and restart upgrade if necessary.

So what I do, I install this solution on the farm from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/government/en-us/campaigns/Pages/SharePoint-Templates.aspx

I do the test again but it issue is still there.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you need to look in the relivant places that you are installing. If its a webpart than look in central admin for wsp's, its a template and/or feature than look in the newley created webapplication features list and in 14 hive to make sure its there!

next performe an iisreset and than go ahead to detach old content database and then attach new content database.

If it doesnt exist e.g. a webpart and you attach the new database than it will be broken on the upgraded webapplication so you would need to redeploy to fix it! and same goes for templates!

You should be testing these changes on a temp test enviroment before doing it on actual live or pre-prod inviroment to make sure you have it right! good luck :)

Comment: But what if it is a feature, and this feature deploys the template, and when i attach it says ok the template is not there, because the future is maybe not activated on this web app, because web app at this moment doesn't have any sites on it

Comment: why dont you create a site on the webapp with the feature enabled? i presume your going to delete the content database anyway once your done! this way you know the feature is active at that webapplication. Its more of a matter of it being on the server within central admin and in 14 hive than being on a site. But if the feature deploys stuff to 14 hive when activated than that is somthing you need todo first and then detach then reattach... this will work as i had a similar issue not long ago!

Comment: I have a content db of sp 2007 with there those templates, and microsoft proposes a new version of the template, can I use it, or i still should use the one for 2007?

Comment: You can still use them, but you need to upgade your content database beforehand. Iv migrated 2003 to 2007 then to 2010. iv already answered here in full on the steps :) http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76018/migration-of-sharepoint-from-2007-to-2010-2013

Comment: Normal way of doing it, what i've read, is that you do pre upgrade check, fix everything, back up, then go install all assemblies on new sp 2010, and test-contentdb, ... in my case i did all that , but i get issues :/

Comment: you need to ignore the error! if you have the feature on the farm and its using the correct 2007 templates as your db file will reference 2007 not 2010 than your fine as the feature and site is already on the migrated content db! it will still moan regardless!

Answer (score 0):

The resolution is to restart the SharePoint machine and run the PowerShell command Test-SPContentDatabase again and everything will be fine.
Source: http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-missingsitedefinition.html